# Why do I have multiple dangling OkHttp ConnectionPool threads

Tags: android, multithreading, okhttp, resource-leak

I have an Android app which is performing HTTP get requests in the background. I'll give some details of how this is performed shortly. I'll focus on describing the issue first.

I've observed in the debugger that `OkHttp ConnectionPool`s are stacking up in the `Threads` window in Android Studio. This is concerning me as it seems to indicate a resource leak and over time these will increase indefinitely (it seems).

My main problem is that I have no idea why this would be happening. I'm almost certain that it's my fault, but I don't have a lead on what to look for. So my general question is:

"What might cause a new pool to be created each time a HTTP request is made?"

Firstly, here's the code I use to do the get request. Note that it's simplified, but I've run with this exact code and see the problem.

```
private TestResult test() {
    final long startTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    final String server = "connectivitycheck.gstatic.com";

    URL url;
    try {
        url = new URL("http", SOME_PATH);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // We shouldn't get here since the url is well known
        return new TestResult(
                "failed to generate url " + e,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime
        );
    }

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    int httpResponseCode;
    try {
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches(false);
        InputStream is = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        httpResponseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return new TestResult(
                e,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime
        );
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    if (httpResponseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT) {
        return new TestResult(
                "invalid error code, expected 204 but got " + httpResponseCode,
                SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime
        );
    }

    return new TestResult(
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - startTime
    );
}
```

So, **when** is this code run...?

Firstly let me say that I've tried running this code from my home activity on my app (in a separate thread - as HTTP isn't allowed on the main android thread). When I do that, everything is fine. I can make multiple requests and never see more than one pool.

The situation in which I run the code and see the issues is as follows:

- I have a background `Service`
- In that service I start a new `Thread`
- In that thread I create an `ExecutorService`:

  ```
  ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
  CompletionService<FutureResult> completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<>(executorService);
  ```
- Using that `ExecutorService` I submit a callable task which runs my `test` method (above).

Note that this may all sound convoluted but there's purpose to all of this. For one, the `ExecutorService` will be performing many other tasks other than just running the `test` method.

I've had a good look for hanging references that somehow might be keeping the underlying HTTP resources alive but I can't see any.

Does anyone with good knowledge of OkHttp know why this might happen? I'm hoping for some insight to help me uncover the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to find out is to set a breakpoint in the ConnectionPool constructor and run your app. That'll show who is creating it. My guess is it's an unrelated class like a crash reporter or analytics library.

Comment: I've already debugged this and I can see that it's definitely OkHttp which is creating the pool. I can't debug the actually OkHttp source though as it's not shipped, so I don't know "why" it's happening. I just know that it is and it's OkHttp doing it :(